# Reading a file line and storing variables of different types

Tags: java, parsing

I am trying to figure out a way to read from the following text file. I am able to get the first integer in the text file which is numLines. After that point, I am able to get the first integer from the line, but am unable to successfully get each individual group of letters.

```
for(int i=0; i < numLines; i++){
   numVariables = Integer.parseInt(fin.next());

    for(int z=0; z < numVariables; z++){
        String line = fin.next();

        int numRules = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(0, 1));

        //Everything up until this point is good

        //read and store first capital letter of every line
        String variable = line.substring(2,3);

        //read and store remaining capital letters that correspond to every line separately
    }
}
```

Text File

```
3
2 A CC DD
3 A AA z v
2 F f a
```

Comment: don't you need a list to store those values?

Comment: Yes. I am having trouble parsing it more than storing it. But yes, either a list or array of size 100 would work.

Comment: @MHZ your question is incomplete - what's the problem?

Comment: Sorry about that, see edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see what is the problem. If you say you have problem of "parsing", you could try:

- read a line (`String line`)
- `split` it into two parts. check here:
  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String, int)

`array =line.split(" ", 2)`

then

```
array[0] is the leading number
array[1] is the rest letters
```

if you want each part, you could `split (" ")` without limit.

if you just want to get those Uppercase words, you can do it by regex:

```
line.split(" ",2); //array[0] is the leading number
```

apply `"(?<= )[A-Z]+(?= )"` on array[1], you get all Upper case words.

is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I need to get all groups of letters separated by spaces, both lower and uppercase.

Comment: @MHZ then split(" "). get the returned array, [0] is the number, rest elements are what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] words = line.split(("\\s+"); // Any whitespace
int numRules = Integer.parseInt(words[0]);
for (int j = 1; j < words.length; ++j) {
   String variable = words[j];
}
```